# When using Sheet clearContents prior to importing CSV data, the result is a blank Sheet

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, import, spreadsheet

Goodday,

I have a Google Sheet with values on Sheet1.
I would like to use Google Apps Script to remove all current values from Sheet1 and import all values from a CSV file.

For the import of the CSV data I'm using the code from https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/08/28/benchmark-importing-csv-data-to-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/#table1 . That works really well and fast (thank you Tanaike) in my other scripts.
For this script I've added some code to clean Sheet1 prior to importing the CSV data (over 9000 rows of data) but the result is that the Sheet is empty when the script is finished. What am I doing wrong (I'm fairly new to Google Apps Script)

```
function importCSV2cleanSheet(){
  var app     = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ws      = app.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      ws.clearContents();       
  var folder  = DriveApp.getFolderById('csvfolderid'); 
  var files   = folder.getFiles();
  
myFile = 'sourcefilename';
  while (files.hasNext()){
      file = files.next();
          if (file == myFile){
            var myID = []
              myID.push(file.getId());                  
          }
  }

  var data    = DriveApp.getFileById(myID).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var sheetId = SpreadsheetApp.openById('destinationsheet')
    .getSheets()[1]
    .getSheetId();

  var resource = {
    requests: [
    {
      pasteData: {
        data: data,
        coordinate: { sheetId: sheetId },
        delimiter: ","
      }
    }
  ]
};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, 'destinationsheet');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with adding this?

```js
ws.clearContents();
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

Comment: great solution. I just realized that I did try utilities.sleep prior to my question but that didn't give me the desired result. Flush does the trick. Another lesson learned for me.  Thank you!