Error while converting data from Excel to CSV using SheetJS Library and Google Apps Script
I have 6 files (5 xlsx, 1 csv) in Google Drive folder which I want to import into 6 different tabs of Google Sheet. Tanaike proposed a solution here that works well if the file size is not big. Unfortunately, my files have thousands of entries (approximately 50000 entries) with file size of 4mb-5mb. Here is the script:
function importExcel1(file, sheet) {
  // Library Key: 1B0eoHz03BVtSZhJAocaGNq94RjoXocz8xGMaLzwVdmAvYW5k8s5Yd360
  // Retrieve values from XLSX file.
  const MD = MicrosoftDocsApp.setFileId(file.getId());
  const srcSS = MD.getSpreadsheet();
  const values = srcSS.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
  // console.log(values); // Confirm the retrieved values in the log.

  MD.end(); // When this line is run, the Spreadsheet created as a temporal file from the XLSX file is removed.
  if (values.length > 0) {
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
}

It gets the data quickly from Excel files, but I get the following error when setting the values in tabs:

Function (importExcel1):
Error: Exceeded maximum execution time

I have tried another approach with SheetJS Library - Code adapted from Tanaike's solution:
 function importFiles() {
  var folderId = 'folder ID'; // ID of the folder where files are stored
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();

    // Skip files that already have "Done" in the name
    if (fileName.includes('Done')) {
      console.log(`Skipping already processed file: ${fileName}`);
      continue;
    }

    var fileType = fileName.slice(0, 6).toLowerCase();
    var sheet;
    var range;

    switch (fileType) {
      case 'parcel':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - shipping");
        range = 'A:T';
        break;
      case 'kit-re':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - kitting");
        range = 'A:G';
        break;
      case 'req-re':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - orders");
        range = 'A:U';
        break;
      case 'billin':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - billing codes");
        range = 'A:G';
        break;
      case 'req_li':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - order line");
        range = 'A:G';
        break;
      case 'packag':
        if (fileName.endsWith('.csv')) {
          sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Manual Extract - Package Grid");
          range = 'A:AO';
        }
        break;
      default:
        continue; // Skip files that do not match the criteria
    }

    if (sheet && range) {
      sheet.getRange(range).clearContent();
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      console.log("Sheet: " + sheet.getName());
      console.log("File: " + file.getName());
      if (file.getMimeType() === MimeType.CSV) {
        importCSV(file, sheet);
      } else {
        convertExcelToCSV(file, sheet);
      }

      // Rename the file by adding "Done" to the end of its name
      // file.setName(fileName + ' Done');
      // console.log(`Processed and renamed file: ${fileName} to ${file.getName()}`);
    }
  }
}

function importCSV(dataOrFile, sheet) {
  var csvData;

  if (typeof dataOrFile === 'string') {
    // If dataOrFile is a string, treat it as CSV data
    csvData = dataOrFile;
  } else {
    // If dataOrFile is a file, extract the data as a string
    csvData = dataOrFile.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  }

  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  console.log(sheetId);

  var resource = {
    requests: [
      {
        pasteData: {
          data: csvData,
          coordinate: { sheetId: sheetId },
          delimiter: ","
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, 'Spreadsheet ID');
}

function convertExcelToCSV(file, sheet) {
  // Get the Excel file as a blob
  var excelBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId()).getBlob();

  // Convert the Blob into a byte array and read it using the XLSX library
  var data = new Uint8Array(excelBlob.getBytes());
  var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });

  // Get the first sheet from the workbook
  var firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
  var firstSheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName];

  var csvData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(firstSheet);

  // Import the CSV data into the Google Sheet
  importCSV(csvData, sheet);
}

I am not sure whether it gets data more efficiently because I keep getting this error:

Error: invalid column -1
encode_col   @ SheetJS.gs:4454
sheet_to_csv @ SheetJS.gs:27507

Is there any other way that we can make a batch request more reliably, any help to resolve this error is much appreciated?


You may try using the full js file (https://git.sheetjs.com/sheetjs/sheetjs/src/branch/master/xlsx.js) instead of the minimized file for better error logs. 2. Does all 5 xlsx files throw the sheetjs error? Try using only one, simple xlsx file to see whether it imports as expected using sheetjs


The issue is with setValues method, it takes time to update the tab with relevant data. We need to use batch to improve it. Just like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68610298/when-using-sheet-clearcontents-prior-to-importing-csv-data-the-result-is-a-blan?rq=2

@TheMaster, I have updated the error for SheetJS library. I am getting this error for all  5 xlsx files

Is there a blank sheet in the file(hidden perhaps?)?

Not a blank sheet, but I realized there are some xlsx files which do not have blank columns at the last, I added blank column at the last and it ran successfully

If possible, share a small xlsx file  which reproduces the same error( after deleting sensitive data and deleting multiple rows and columns, and deleting all sheets except one, i.e., the minimal file needed to reproduce the error)

Here is the link to xlsx sample file which produces an error message when trying to convert it into csv: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nbrbmPIMuVcOkvRSFk92HzVUDCJ571Fe/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107464693787053536449&rtpof=true&sd=true

First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About Here is the link to xlsx sample file which produces an error message when trying to convert it into csv:, if you used your bottom script, unfortunately, when I tested your script using your provided XLSX file, no error occurs. values of const values = Utilities.parseCsv(csv); have valid values without error. So, can you provide your current script for correctly replicating it?

Thank you for your reply, I just tested the script,  after removing empty columns from the last, all files are processed. Can you please test the script on this file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nbrbmPIMuVcOkvRSFk92HzVUDCJ571Fe/edit?gid=1640554289#gid=1640554289

Also, can you please assist why this error occurs? The error showed col: -1 while all xlsx files had more than 5 columns.

Thank you for replying. About Thank you for your reply, I just tested the script, after removing empty columns from the last, all files are processed. Can you please test the script on this file: docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/…, when I tested your provided file, no error occurs. I apologize for this situation. So, can you provide your current script for correctly replicating it?

By the way, about Unfortunately, my files have thousands of entries (approximately 50000 entries) with file size of 4mb-5mb. Here is the script:, in this case, where is the error line in your showing script? I'm worried that in your situation, it might be required to use Sheets API instead of Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp).

Basically, I am looking to update all xlsx file data (without converting into CSV first) into Google sheet using Sheets API to minimize the execution time, can we update the data directly from xlsx to sheet?

Thank you for replying. About can we update the data directly from xlsx to sheet?, I have to apologize for the current specification. In the current stage, Sheets API can be used to Google Spreadsheets. Unfortunately, Sheets API cannot be directly used for XLSX data. In this case, it is required to convert XLSX data to Google Spreadsheet. By this, the values can be used with Sheets API.

Can you please suggest a better approach?

convert xlsx data to Spreadsheet and then Use Sheets API
converting the xlsx to csv and then use this data with Sheets API


Thank you for replying. About Can you please suggest a better approach? 1. convert xlsx data to Spreadsheet and then Use Sheets API 2. converting the xlsx to csv and then use this data with Sheets API, in the case of converting from XLSX and CXSV to Google Spreadsheet, it can be achieved by Drive API. By this, the converted Spreadsheet can be used with Sheets API. But, there is an important point.

In your situation, how much total number of cells are included in I have 6 files (5 xlsx, 1 csv) in Google Drive folder? If it is over 10,000,000, your goal I want to import into 6 different tabs of Google Sheet. cannot be achieved. I'm also worried about it.

Luckily, number of cells are less than 10,000,000. I have 5 files in xlsx, so should I first convert them into CSV and then use SheetsAPI or is it better to first convert them into Google Spreadsheet and then use the Sheets API to paste values in tabs?

Thank you for replying. I understood your total number of cells. About the flow, 1. Convert XLSX and CSV files to Google Spreadsheets. 2. Retrieve all values from the converted Spreadsheets. (Each file includes only one tab?) 3. Put values into each sheet in the destination Spreadsheet.

yes, that is the ideal workflow, can you please suggest a solution/modification for this? I have added my full code to the question as well

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand the answer to my question Each file includes only one tab?.

it means data from each file would go to each tab, so data from 6 different files will go to 6 different tabs of google sheet, above script in the question shows this approach

Thank you for repling. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

In your situation, how about the following modification?
In this modified script, the following steps are run.

Convert XLSX or CSV data to Google Spreadsheet.
Retrieve values from the converted Spreadsheet using Sheets API.
Put values to each sheet in the destination Spreadsheet.
Delete the converted Spreadsheet.

Before you use this script, please enable Drive API v3 and Sheets API at Advanced Google services. And, please set your folder ID.
I guessed that in your situation, you want to retrieve the values from the 1st sheet in each XLSX.
Modified script 1:
In this script, after all values are retrieved, the values are put into each sheet.
function importFiles() {
  var folderId = '###'; // ID of the folder where files are stored
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles(); // or const files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).searchFiles(`mimeType='${MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL}' or mimeType='${MimeType.CSV}' and trashed=false`);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var data = []; // Added
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();

    // Skip files that already have "Done" in the name
    if (fileName.includes('Done')) {
      console.log(`Skipping already processed file: ${fileName}`);
      continue;
    }

    var fileType = fileName.slice(0, 6).toLowerCase();
    var sheet;
    var range;

    switch (fileType) {
      case 'parcel':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - shipping");
        range = 'A:T';
        break;
      case 'kit-re':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - kitting");
        range = 'A:G';
        break;
      case 'req-re':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - orders");
        range = 'A:U';
        break;
      case 'billin':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - billing codes");
        range = 'A:G';
        break;
      case 'req_li':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - order line");
        range = 'A:G';
        break;
      case 'packag':
        if (fileName.endsWith('.csv')) {
          sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Manual Extract - Package Grid");
          range = 'A:AO';
        }
        break;
      default:
        continue; // Skip files that do not match the criteria
    }

    if (sheet && range) {
      sheet.getRange(range).clearContent();
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      console.log("Sheet: " + sheet.getName());
      console.log("File: " + file.getName());

// I modified the below script.
      const id = Drive.Files.copy({ mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS }, file.getId()).id;
      const { values } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(id, "A:ZZZ");
      data.push({ values, range: sheet.getName() });
      Drive.Files.remove(id);
    }
  }
  if (data.length == 0) return;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, ss.getId());
}

Modified script 2:
In this script, each value of each file is put into each sheet in the while loop.
function importFiles() {
  var folderId = '###'; // ID of the folder where files are stored
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();

    // Skip files that already have "Done" in the name
    if (fileName.includes('Done')) {
      console.log(`Skipping already processed file: ${fileName}`);
      continue;
    }

    var fileType = fileName.slice(0, 6).toLowerCase();
    var sheet;
    var range;

    switch (fileType) {
      case 'parcel':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - shipping");
        range = 'A:T';
        break;
      case 'kit-re':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - kitting");
        range = 'A:G';
        break;
      case 'req-re':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - orders");
        range = 'A:U';
        break;
      case 'billin':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - billing codes");
        range = 'A:G';
        break;
      case 'req_li':
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import - order line");
        range = 'A:G';
        break;
      case 'packag':
        if (fileName.endsWith('.csv')) {
          sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Manual Extract - Package Grid");
          range = 'A:AO';
        }
        break;
      default:
        continue; // Skip files that do not match the criteria
    }

    if (sheet && range) {
      sheet.getRange(range).clearContent();
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      console.log("Sheet: " + sheet.getName());
      console.log("File: " + file.getName());

      const id = Drive.Files.copy({ mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS }, file.getId()).id;
      const { values } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(id, "A:ZZZ");
      if (values.length == 0) continue;
      Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values }, ss.getId(), sheet.getName(), { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
      Drive.Files.remove(id);
      // Utilities.sleep(3000); // This line might be required to be used.
    }
  }
}

References:

Method: files.copy
Method: spreadsheets.values.get
Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate
Method: spreadsheets.values.update

